# page number in the Crystal report don't increases

Tags: crystal-reports, page-numbering

The problem is the "special fields" > "page number" won't increases in the pages and the **total page count** is 1, while the report has more than 100 pages! 
In the all of pages it is "1" or if I changed it to "n of m" then it will be "1 of 1"! My report is simple and i have just one "group by" in that. So what is wrong?
Thank you all

Comment: So you get the page number 1 on every page?

Answer (score 2):

If you always get "Page 1" on every page, make sure that in the Section Expert, under the Paging tab, you don't have "Reset Page Number After" option checked for any of your report sections.